# How to get a list of items from one table and total of their related items from anther in mySql?

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I'm going to have a list of all `order_status` items with total number of related orders. I tried to use inner join and left join, but none of them worked for me.

```
select
order_status.order_status_id, order_status.name, sum(order.order_id)
where language_id = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7efcbe

Here are tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
    `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `order_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_status` (
    `order_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`order_status_id`,`language_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query, perhaps your looking for this data --

```
select os.order_status_id,os.name,count(o.order_id) 
from order_status as os 
left outer join `order` o on os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id
group by os.order_status_id,os.name
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select os.order_status_id, os.name, sum(o.order_id)
from `order_status` os JOIN `order` o on os.order_status_id=o.order_status_id
AND o.language_id = 1
GROUP BY o.order_status_id;
```

Comment: Could you update your answer and explain what you are doing. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

```
select order_status.order_status_id,order_status.name,count(o.order_id) AS no_of_order
from order_status 
left outer join `order` o on order_status.order_status_id = o.order_status_id
group by order_status.order_status_id,order_status.name
```

you can also visit http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7efcbe/22